# Raspberry pi GPIO don't work

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

I am using the GPIO ports of raspberry pi through python(idle). I set the GPIO pins high in the code and compile it. The code compiles but the led attached to pins do not turn on. I do not understand the problem. I can't figure out what i am doing wrong.
Here is the code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(8, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(12, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(7, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(8, GPIO.HIGH)
```

Comment: did you fry your GPIO pins? I've read somewhere that its very easy to do. Anyway there is probably a better stack exchange site for things like this. you may get better answers there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a resistor(~200 ohms) connected to the LED ? Without a resistor to set the local voltage, the LED alone is useless.
  Resistor calculator : http://led.linear1.org/1led.wiz

Anyway, since electronics can go wrong from various reasons (software bug, driver incompatibilies, bus saturated, busted components, and so on ...), can you try to follow the follwing tutorial from step 5 up to step 8 and tells us when it bugs : http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/temperature/#step-five ?

Comment: I am using a resistor. I have tested the led circuit i-e the led and the resistor separately with a power supply and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

did you connect the long leg of your led to plus? it won't work the other way round ...