# Cannot put all GPIO pins to high 4 channel motor controller

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, motordriver

I'm trying to run 4 motors with my raspberry pi using a cytron 4 channel motor driver.

My code works for reverse and for left/right turns but I cannot put all GPIO pins to high at the same time.

parts of the code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

MOTOR1Direction = 11
MOTOR1Enable = 13
etc for other 3 motors

GPIO.setup(MOTOR1Direction,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(MOTOR1Enable,GPIO.OUT)
etc for the other 3 motors

p1 = GPIO.PWM(MOTOR1Enable, 100)
etc for the other 3 motors

def forward(pwmVal):
  GPIO.output(MOTOR1Direction, GPIO.HIGH)
  GPIO.output(MOTOR2Direction, GPIO.HIGH)
  GPIO.output(MOTOR3Direction, GPIO.HIGH)
  GPIO.output(MOTOR4Direction, GPIO.HIGH)
  p1.start(pwmVal)
  p2.start(pwmVal)
  p3.start(pwmVal)
  p4.start(pwmVal)

def reverse(pwmVal):
  GPIO.output(MOTOR1Direction, GPIO.LOW)
  GPIO.output(MOTOR2Direction, GPIO.LOW)
  GPIO.output(MOTOR3Direction, GPIO.LOW)
  GPIO.output(MOTOR4Direction, GPIO.LOW)
  p1.start(pwmVal)
  p2.start(pwmVal)
  p3.start(pwmVal)
  p4.start(pwmVal)

def left(pwmVal):
  GPIO.output(MOTOR1Direction, GPIO.HIGH)
  GPIO.output(MOTOR2Direction, GPIO.HIGH)
  GPIO.output(MOTOR3Direction, GPIO.LOW)
  GPIO.output(MOTOR4Direction, GPIO.LOW)
  p1.start(pwmVal)
  p2.start(pwmVal)
  p3.start(pwmVal)
  p4.start(pwmVal)
```

So when I run reverse(100) it works, same for left/right, but when I run forward(100) nothing happens. If I change any one of the HIGH's in the forward code to LOW it works?

Comment: Which pins did you use for the motors?

Comment: the Pi's GPIO pins for all of them, like 11 & 13 for motor 1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Raspberry pi GPIO don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20354915/raspberry-pi-gpio-dont-work)

Comment: Not a duplicate? Very different problem as I do have connection but only have issues when ALL 4 pins are high

Comment: I mean which pins specifically. Maybe the problem might be related to the specific pins you used, or it's a power issue. It was just to have all the information.

Comment: hi, they are attached to: 
11, 13, 12, 15, 29, 32, 31 & 33